# Creating a single point on a specific distance on a line in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, point, vector, line, distance

I'm trying to find a plugin of some sorts to help me create a point along a line at a certain distance. This does not require a import from a CSV file, just a field where I can insert a certain distance in meters. And where I can select the line where it should measure from and select from which side of the line I want to start measuring.

I'm searching for quite a while now and I'm only finding a lot of plugins which nearly do the same but most of these plugins require CSV import, or Chainage, which I don't need nor want.

I'm working with specialized electric fault meters which gives me distances along a cable where there should be a problem of some sorts, and it would be awesome if I could simply input the distance and get an exact location along the cable I've drawn.

PS: I'm not very skilled with coding, I can do some basics but that's about it.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `points along lines``tool? If so, how does it not suit your needs?

Comment: What you want is probably linear referencing (also called dynamic segmentation), have a look at the LRS plugin

Comment: well @Erik the problem is that when i have a cable which is, say 2,5km and i have a disturbance at say 120m, is get a lot of points which are quite unnesecary.

Answer (score 2):

The ["Points along geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) algorithm will add the point for you, but there is no option to only add one point:

> This algorithm creates a points layer, with points distributed along
> the lines of an input vector layer. The distance between points
> (measured along the line) is defined as a parameter. Start and end
> offset distances can be defined, so the first and last point will not
> fall exactly on the line's first and last nodes. These start and end
> offsets are defined as distances, measured along the line from the
> first and last nodes of the lines.

I guess that if you use the *Start offset* to specify your distance and then choose a sufficiently large value (larger than the maximum line length) for the *Distance* between the points you should achieve what you want.